# Python - entry doesn't have attribute widget

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes, widget, tkinter-entry

I am trying to make a simple user input tkinter GUI where users can input basic detail. Although I've searched the web, I cannot conquer this issue:

```
    from tkinter import *


def user():
    print(user_entry.widget.get())
    print(email_entry.widget.get())
    print(pass1_entry.widget.get())
    print(pass2_entry.widget.get())
    pass

#main loop initial visual
main_window = Tk()
main_window.title('Register')
main_window.geometry('250x350+200+200')
main_window.configure(bg = 'Blue')

wel = Label(main_window, text="""Hello, thanks for using my software.
Please put in the details, it will be kept
safe and sent to our database""", bg = 'white')
wel.place(x = 0,y = 10)


username_lab = Label(main_window, text="Username:").place(x=0, y=64)

#us = StringVar()
user_entry = Entry(main_window)
user_entry.place(x=70,y=64)
user_entry.bind("<Return>", user())

email_lab = Label(main_window, text="Email: ").place(x=0, y=90)

#emi = StringVar()
email_entry = Entry(main_window)
email_entry.place(x=70,y=90)
email_entry.bind("<Return>", user())

pass_lab = Label(main_window, text="Password:").place(x=0, y=116)

#pas1 = StringVar()
pass1_entry = Entry(main_window, show="*")
pass1_entry.place(x=70,y=116)
pass1_entry.bind("<Return>", user())

pass_lab = Label(main_window, text="Password repeat:").place(x=0, y=140)

#pas2 = StringVar()
pass2_entry = Entry(main_window, show="*")
pass2_entry.place(x=100,y=140)
pass2_entry.bind("<Return>", user())


ok = Button(main_window, text="OK", command = user(), width=8).place(x=15, y= 175)




main_window.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error and I can't figure out why. Please help for at least one thing (ie username) and the rest would follow similar rules. :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Milosz/Desktop/Programming/Register/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    user_entry.bind("<Return>", user())
  File "C:/Users/Milosz/Desktop/Programming/Register/main.py", line 5, in user
    print(user_entry.widget.get())
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'widget'
```

Comment: Why do you think `user_entry` has a `widget` attribute? What do you expect that attribute to have that is different from the `user_entry` object itself?

Comment: I wasn't too sure. So how would you write the code so that it would print the input on the SHELL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use `get()` on an entry field you need to only use it on the variable name in this case. `widget()` is not doing what you think its doing here and is not needed.

In your `user():` class replace all the print statement.

From:

```
def user():
    print(user_entry.widget.get())
    print(email_entry.widget.get())
    print(pass1_entry.widget.get())
    print(pass2_entry.widget.get())
    pass
```

To:

```
def user():
    print(user_entry.get())
    print(email_entry.get())
    print(pass1_entry.get())
    print(pass2_entry.get())
    # removed pass as it is not needed and does nothing here.
```

This should print the contents to the console.